# Multiple slide shows without extensive cut-and-paste

Tags: javascript, css, html, slideshow

I have this slideshow (I have modified from some code [origional source](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider))

Here is a jsfiddle link:

[Full source here](http://jsfiddle.net/supagu/K3Esz/)

The CSS looks to be hard coded such that if I try to display two different slideshows on the same page then I run in to problems where the buttons from the second slideshow controls the first slideshow.

Is there some way I can modify things to allow multiple separate slide shows on a webpage?

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="slideshow-wrap">
    <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="button-1"></label>
```

CSS snippet:

```
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That slider you are using was the first slider I used in 2012. Pretty cool. BUT, I highly suggest you check out [Responsiveslides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) - It is super awesome and I use it anytime I need a slider. It might take a little more styling depending on your case but is really cabable and I've already checked - and it's sliders are specific enough as not to step on one another. [a fiddle with 2 sliders as an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5Ch7c/)

### HTML

Really simple markup. Whatever you want to shove in the list items.

```
<ul class="rslides">
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/150-1" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/150-2" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/150-3" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

Base css is simple too - and there are some themes. This way you are in full control

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```